# Images 404 in HTML report after Grails upgrade

Tags: grails, dynamic-reports

We've been using Dynamic Reports directly in our Grails 1.3.7 app with great success. However, when we upgraded to Grails 2.2.4, the images are broken in the HTML view. The hyperlink generated leads to a 404, even for static content such as logos. All the other reports work fine. I am thinking the maybe the image factory servlet needs to be registered in web.xml or something like that. Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: Can you include the URI for the broken images? Are you using DynamicJasper (via Grails plugin or not - "directly" suggests not)?

Comment: /appname/image?image=img_0_0_0_0

We are not using the Grails plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. (Thanks to Ricardo over at DynamicReports help forum!)

The image servlet must indeed be registered in /src/templates/war/web.xml configuration. We did not have to do this in Grails 1.3.7. Hope this helps someone else!

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ImageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>net.sf.jasperreports.j2ee.servlets.ImageServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>   
    <servlet-name>ImageServlet</servlet-name>   
    <url-pattern>/image</url-pattern>   
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create a new application and to use a visual diff software like `meld` in order to compare your project directory vs the new application directory. You can find that common files like `BuildConfig.groovy` or `Config.groovy` could to need massive corrections. There are another files that you should to review after the migration.

Comment: Thanks. We've been nibbling away at upgrading our 1.3.7 app for about a year now with each software release, and this is the last item. We've spent time cleaning up Config.groovy, etc. in the process.